# update array of object without mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm following a react tutorial but I'm lost. I don't understand starting line 9.

[image]

so I tried to make a little miarature

```
const updateTodo = (list, updated) => {
   const index = list.findIndex(item => item.id === updated.id)
   return [
   ...list.slice(0,index),
   updated,
   ...list.slice(index+1)
   ]
}
```

https://jsbin.com/sifihocija/2/edit?js,console but failed to produce the result that the author did, what's wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Issue is in this line:

`const index = list.findIndex(item => item.id === updated.id)`

updated is an `array`, to access the id, you need to specify the `index` also,
for other `array` you are using `loop`, so `item` will be the each `object` of the `array`, and `item.id` will give you the `id` of each `object`, try this:

`const index = list.findIndex(item => item.id === updated[0].id)`

```js
const arr = [
  {id:1,name:'hello'},
  {id:2,name:'hai'}
]

const arr2 = [
  {id:2,name:'this should be a new string'}
]

const updateTodo = (list, updated) => {
   const index = list.findIndex(item => item.id === updated[0].id);
   return [
   ...list.slice(0,index),
   ...updated,
   ...list.slice(index+1)
   ]
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(updateTodo(arr,arr2)))
```

Check the working code: https://jsbin.com/pazakujava/edit?js,console

Let me know if you need any help in this.

Comment: can u explain why in the author doesn't have to do so? I mean do updated[0].id

Comment: the tutorial is here https://egghead.io/lessons/react-update-data-in-a-list-without-mutations

Comment: because in his case, arr2 will be an object, like this: `const arr2 = 
  {id:2,name:'this should be a new string'}` you can try this arr2, ur code will also work :)

Comment: ah arr2 should be an object, it shouldn't be an array, I think that's my mistake, that doesn't make sense if arr2 is an array.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler and cleaner using `Array.map`:

```
const updateTodo = (list, updated) =>
    list.map((item) => {
        if (item.id !== updated.id) {
            return item;
        }

        return updated;
    });
```